# How to take input in beginning of the program?

Tags: linux, shell

I am making a program which needs the user input in the beginning of the program if you don't get my question i will give you an example:

```
./script.sh "some-input"
```

So, I want the input in the beginning of the program. I think the input will be stored in a variable. If yes, Then please tell me in which variable it is stored. I am a Linux rookie please never hesitate to correct the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we have:

```
some_program word1 word2 word3
```

> ```
> $0 would contain "some_program"
> $1 would contain "word1"
> $2 would contain "word2"
> $3 would contain "word3"
> ```
>
> and $4 fourth argumet and so on

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is working for me very well!!

Answer (score 0):

The program arguments are in $1, $2, and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much, Washingon! I am so sorry that I cannot take this as an answer even though this works because I have got the answer faster but still thank you!